# Child controls grow unlimited in custom XAML control. What's wrong?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I've implemented a Windows 8 XAML `VisibilitySwitchControl` that displays the first child on certain condition; otherwise the other controls are shown. The code is as follows

```cs
[ContentProperty(Name = "Items")]
public class VisibilitySwitchControl : ItemsControl
{
    public VisibilitySwitchControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(VisibilitySwitchControl);
        if (Items != null)
            Items.VectorChanged += OnItemsChanged;
    }

    public bool ShowFirst
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowFirstProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowFirstProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowFirstProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowFirst", typeof(bool), typeof(VisibilitySwitchControl), new PropertyMetadata(true, OnShowFirstChanged));

    public object VisibleContent
    {
        get { return GetValue(VisibleContentProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(VisibleContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VisibleContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("VisibleContent", typeof(object), typeof(VisibilitySwitchControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    private static void OnShowFirstChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var visibilityItemsControl = d as VisibilitySwitchControl;
        if (visibilityItemsControl != null)
        {
            visibilityItemsControl.Evaluate();
        }
    }

    void OnItemsChanged(IObservableVector<object> sender, IVectorChangedEventArgs evt)
    {
        Evaluate();
    }

    void Evaluate()
    {
        if (Items != null && Items.Any())
        {
            var controls = Items.OfType<FrameworkElement>().ToList();
            for (var i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    VisibleContent = controls[i];
                    controls[i].Visibility = ShowFirst ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    controls[i].Visibility = !ShowFirst ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            VisibleContent = null;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I place two `ListView` controls inside my `VisibilitySwitchControl` the ListView can grow in way that it is larger than the page and no scrollbars are shown. It doesn't stop a the parent containers bounds.

```xml
<custom:VisibilitySwitchControl ShowFirst="{Binding Path=IsFirstLevelNav}">
    <ListView x:Name="FirstListView"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ..., Mode=TwoWay}"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            />
    <ListView x:Name="SecondListView"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding ..., Mode=TwoWay}"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            />
</custom:VisibilitySwitchControl>
```

How can I enforce a `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` behavior of the children? If I remove my control and place only one the lists directly in the code, everything works as expected.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to stretch the Height of the listview try binding it to the actual height of the parent

Heres the code part you need to include

```
Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=parentContainer}"
```

where `parentContainer` is the name of the `custom:VisibilitySwitchControl` you are using . this will bind the height to the parent container's display height. Try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is that you scroll one ListView and then when you reach the end it show the second ListView then you just need to add a ScrollViewer around the ItemPresenter inside the style of VisibilitySwitchControl and disable the ListView ScrollViewer. Just note that it mean that you will lost the virtualisation inside the ListView.

If what you want is each ListView taking half the screen than the easiest is probably to just set a Fix height for each items depending on  `Window.Current.Bounds.Height` and register for `Window.Current.SizeChanged` to update it when the windows heigh changed (make sure to unregister it in unloaded to prevent memory leak).
 An alternative which I think would be more complicated, would be to change the ItemsPanel of VisibilitySwitchControl to something else (by default it is a Stack panel so it will grow larger than the screen) like for example to a Grid in which you set as many row with star heigh as items you have (and then you will need to set the row of each item) or by creating a custom Panel.